# Apply class binding to combobox in python

Tags: python, combobox, tkinter, key-bindings

Is it possible to apply class binding to comboboxes?

Like for example with Entries

```
self.master.bind_class("Entry", "<Button-3>", self.rClicker)
```

I am trying to do the same with Combobox but whatever i write it does not work

```
self.master.bind_class("Combobox", "<Button-3>", self.rClicker)
```

or

```
self.master.bind_class("ttk.Combobox", "<Button-3>", self.rClicker)
```

Comment: No which keyword should i use? "Combobox"??

Answer (score 1):

The widget class for `ttk.Combobox` is `TCombobox`:

```
self.master.bind_class("TCombobox", self.rClicker)
```

You can get any widget to print its class with the `winfo_class` method:

```
cb = ttk.Combobox(...)
print("class: %s" % cb.winfo_class())
```